# Showing values from an expression

Tags: angularjs

Im new to AngularJS and I have encountered a problem when it comes to showing values from an expression in a dropdown. 
I have noticed that when i hardcode the values like this then it works:

```
<select ng-model="selectSort" ng-change="changeSort(selectSort)" ng-init="selectSort='0'">
<option value="0">Ändringsdatum, nyast överst</option>
<option value="1">Ändringsdatum, äldst överst</option>
<option value="2">Sidtitel</option>
```

What i'm wondering is, how do i get the values from an expressions like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectSort" ng-change="changeSort(selectSort)" ng-init="{{SORT_TYPE.date}}">
<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.date}}">Ändringsdatum, nyast överst</option>
<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.dateDesc}}">Ändringsdatum, äldst överst</option>
<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.label}}">Sidtitel</option>
```

I have searched everywhere and tryed everything that comes to my mind.

**EDIT**

```
angular.module('directives.sort', [])

.constant('SORT_TYPE', {
    date: '0',
    dateDesc: '1',
    label: '2'

})   

 .directive('sort', function (SORT_TYPE) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         templateUrl: '/common/directives/sort/sort.html', 
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.SORT_TYPE = SORT_TYPE;                
         }
     };
 })
```

/K

Comment: where is your SORT_TYPE?

Comment: Can you show us your controller too?

Comment: @MattLishman I've updated the question, and I use a directive instead of an controller

Comment: Are you actually using the sort directive anywhere? Like `<div sort>`?

Comment: @MattLishman yes i'm using sort directive in multiple <div>'s

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect your controller to look something like this then:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.SORT_TYPE = {
    date: 'some date',
    dateDesc: 'some description',
    label: 'Date'
  };
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question and I use a directive instead of an controller

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code in plunker seems to work.

I put your template inline.

I would guess your template is being referenced incorrectly or you are using your directive incorrectly.

I also removed your ng-init because that was causing a console error.
Ng-init is used to evaluate an expression, there was no expression in there.

Your code should look something similar to this.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5cKQIYzfjRDuBXcpAcyT?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="directives.sort">
      <div sort></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('directives.sort', [])

.constant('SORT_TYPE', {
    date: '0',
    dateDesc: '1',
    label: '2'

})   

 .directive('sort', function (SORT_TYPE) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: '<select ng-model="selectSort" ng-change="changeSort(selectSort)" ng-init="{{SORT_TYPE.date}}">'+
'<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.date}}">Ändringsdatum, nyast överst</option>'+
'<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.dateDesc}}">Ändringsdatum, äldst överst</option>'
+'<option value="{{SORT_TYPE.label}}">Sidtitel</option>', 
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.SORT_TYPE = SORT_TYPE;                
         }
     };
 })
```

Comment: Unforunetly this didnt work. i checked if i get any values at all by using alert(JSON.stringify()) and it seems that i get the values, they are just not appearing in the place that I want them to appear. When i checked the HTML I noticed that Angular for some weird reason adds an empty <option></option> tag with no values. That's also something I have checked up and the only answer that I found was as shown in the first code snippet with hardcoded values. Now unfortunatelly this is not the case since im using expressions.

Comment: @K.Oleksiak Edited the answer with a plunker link.

Comment: Indeed, your solution in the plunker link works. The problem is that when i check the HTML after launching the projekt, another <option value="? string: 0 ?"></option> appears before the rest, leaving the dropdown empty and not showing the first value which in this case is the optiontag with the value="0".

Comment: @K.Oleksiak I don't see that in the plunker. Can you replicate it there?
Otherwise, if all you want to do is have a default for your select: `<option selected="selected">`. Or am I misunderstanding you?